# How to limit vertically the extent of an OpenLayers map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

When I pan north, the map goes out and I see the white background of my HTML. I want to pan vertically and the map to block when it reaches the top (or bottom, respectively).

I have tried to put bounds, but this solution puts also bounds horizontally. I want to be able to pan infinitely left or right, but limit the panning up and down.

How could I do this?

Thanks

EDIT 1:
I preferred not to extend the OpenLayers core. I want the solution to cover all the pan, drag, zoom cases. A general solution would be fine, I think. I heard there was an option in the map initialization, that restricts the extent only vertically. Do you know anything about it?

[image: Map out on pan north]

Comment: Specifically with the pan tool bar or does this include dragging the map?

Comment: @JohnBarça, I don't understand your question. I want to drag freely left and right, but I want the vertical drag to stop when I reach the top/bottom end of the map. Check out the image I show. This is what happens now, and what I want to avoid: the white space above, by dragging too much upwards.

Comment: OK, I have answered the question for panning, and you need dragging, sorry. I will update my answer.

Comment: I need both. Pan + Drag! :) Thank you, @JohnBarça

Comment: OK. Will do drag later. Can you confirm if pan works for you, as I have done it?

Comment: @JohnBarça, I might try your solution, but I preferred not to extend the OpenLayers core. And I think this might not cover all the pan, drag, zoom cases. A general solution would be better, I think. I heard there was an options in the map initialization, that restricts the extent only vertically. Do you know anything about it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me which CRS/SRID you are using and what you would like to limit the North/South map extents too, so as to make a working exmaple?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by overriding the buttonDown function of [OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/PanZoom.js) which starts off like this:

```
    buttonDown: function (evt) {
        if (!OpenLayers.Event.isLeftClick(evt)) {
            return;
        }

        switch (this.action) {
            case "panup":
                this.map.pan(0, -this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                break;
        switch (this.action) {
            case "pandown":
                this.map.pan(0, this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                break;
        ... etc
```

So instead of this, you can do:

```
OpenLayes.Control.PanZoom.prototype.buttonDown = function (evt){
       if (!OpenLayers.Event.isLeftClick(evt)) {
            return;
        }
        //get map bounds
        var mapBounds=map.getExtent(); 

         switch (this.action) {
            case "panup":
                //add you code here to check extents
                if (mapBounds.top < some_number){ 
                   this.map.pan(0, -this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                   break;
                }
        switch (this.action) {
            case "pandown":
                 //add you code here to check extents
                if (mapBounds.bottom > some_number){ 
                    this.map.pan(0, this.getSlideFactor("h"));
                    break;
                }
             //leave this as it was, as you don't care about left/right
             case "panleft":
                  this.map.pan(-this.getSlideFactor("w"), 0);
                  break;
             ....
```

etc. Note you will have to fill out the rest of the function, as it was, as you are overriding it. You want to make sure this function is added after OpenLayers.js loads.